# Tag synonym suggestions (updated)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

**I will now put each suggestion in an answer to this question. Feel free to vote on each answer**

[human](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human) and [human-skills](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-skills) synonym of [physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology)

[rape](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rape) synonym of [sexual-abuse](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-abuse)

[fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride) synonym of [fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation)

[cost](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost) synonym of [price](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price)

[congress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) synonym of [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

[beer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer) synonym of [alcohol](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol)

[cigarettes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cigarettes) and [smoking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoking) and perhaps [nicotine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicotine) and/or [tobacco](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tobacco) (not sure which should be the main tag)

[programming-productivity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-productivity) synonym of [productivity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity)

[fitness](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) synonym of [exercise](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise)

[hackers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hackers) synonym of [hacking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking)

[vehicle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) synonym of [cars](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars)

[hollywood](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood) synonym of [movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies)

We have [medications](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medications) and [drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs) should they be merged? We also have [recreational-drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-drugs) and [pharmaceutical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmaceutical)

We have [money](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and [currency](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) should they be merged?

we have [heart-attack](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-attack), maybe we can make a more generic [cardiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardiology) tag?

[cell-phone](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-phone) and [mobile-phones](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) seem like they are half merged. They are listed on the tag synonym page with pending (1) next to it.

I question the value of the following tags: [time](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), [causality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality) (seems too much like a meta tag to me), [force](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force), [lifestyle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle), [networks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networks)

I am also questioning the need for both [teeth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teeth) and [dentistry](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dentistry).

**Feel free to disagree, discuss and comment**

Comment: [tags] and [tag-synonyms] (I'm kidding!)

Comment: I am also questioning the need for both [tag:teeth] and [tag:dentistry].

Comment: @SamIAm can you make a separate answer for each tag so the community can discuss them? at the moment it's not clear what the consensus is :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz done...

Comment: We have [crime], [organized-crime] and [criminology].

Comment: actually this might fail, if users agree or disagree with many of the answers, the serial voting script might kick in. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180/203115

Comment: and today all my votes have been undone

Answer (score 3):

<strike>[rape] synonym of [sexual-abuse]</strike> *(done)*

Answer (score 3):

<strike>we have [heart-attack], maybe we can make a more generic [cardiology] tag? or even [heart-disease]?</strike> *(done)*

Comment: cardiology would be consistent

Comment: I tagged a question with cardiology so now it exists.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>[teeth] synonym of [dentistry]</strike> *(done)*

Answer (score 2):

[human](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human) and [human-skills](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-skills) synonym of [physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology)

Comment: Yes, I find these particularly irritating.

Answer (score 2):

[fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride) synonym of [fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation)

Comment: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/should-we-stop-adding-fluoride

Answer (score 2):

[cost](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost) synonym of [price](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/price)

Answer (score 2):

[programming-productivity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-productivity) synonym of [productivity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productivity)

Answer (score 2):

[hackers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hackers) synonym of [hacking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>[cell-phone] and [mobile-phones] seem like they are half merged. They are listed on the tag synonym page with pending (1) next to it.</strike> *(done)*

Answer (score 1):

[fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation)  is more specific than [fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride) so this one should go the other way.

[congress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) is not a synonym of U.S. it should be left alone or just removed from the one question and possibly recreated if a larger amount of questions are asked in the future.

[beer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer) seems to be used responsibly and classifies the handful of questions better than alcohol would

[vehicle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) should be the master tag not [cars](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars)

[cardiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardiology) seems a bit to general for the current questions, [heart-failure](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-failure) might be better. I would hesitate to generalize too far when there aren't really any general questions that would benefit.

For the drug tags perhaps merge [drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs) into [recreational-drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-drugs) and leave [medications](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medications). I think we should have separate tags for legal prescription medication questions and illicit drug use.

Comment: Of course [tag:congress] isn't a a synonym of [tag:united-states] but it is being used in lieu of [tag:united-states] when that is the more appropriate tag to use. Maybe it is just a few mistagged questions. I remember retagging a few of them, a while ago, but looks like it is currently being used only once.

Comment: I don't feel there is much of a value of having both [tag:beer] and [tag:alcohol], as well as having [tag:wine], [tag:vodka], [tag:rum], [tag:cider], ...

Comment: Examples of questions that can benefit from [tag:cardiology]: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14262/are-heart-attacks-due-to-vitamin-c-deficiency http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1231/are-saturated-fats-unhealthy/10850 http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8024/does-an-aspirin-a-day-have-health-benefits http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/can-a-person-die-of-heart-attack-caused-by-extreme-happiness/2397 http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/is-eating-eggs-bad-for-me/1193

Comment: having beer as a separate entity doesn't mean every other alcohol needs their own tag, its alright to have a popular subsection have its own tag and have a general category tag

Comment: @SamIAm I suppose cardiology would be ok, even though 2/5 of your examples would fit under heart-attack :)

Comment: I'm only going by precedence here. We have [tag:dentistry], [tag:psychiatry], [tag:ophthalmology], [tag:neurology], [tag:dermatology], etc... :)

Answer (score 1):

[beer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beer) synonym of [alcohol](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alcohol)

Answer (score 1):

[cigarettes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cigarettes) and [smoking](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smoking) and perhaps [nicotine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nicotine) and/or [tobacco](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tobacco) (not sure which should be the main tag)

Answer (score 1):

[vehicle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) synonym of [cars](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cars)

Comment: Bicycles, trucks, or trains, are vehicles too.

Comment: Swap that synonym. [vehicle] is more general and international. Or go with 'automobile'

Comment: @gerrit then maybe we should just retag all the vehicle questions with the correct type of vehicle. :)

Answer (score 1):

[hollywood](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hollywood) synonym of [movies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies)

Comment: Hollywood is also a neighborhood...

Answer (score 1):

We have [medications](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medications) and [drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugs) should they be merged? We also have [recreational-drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-drugs) and [pharmaceutical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmaceutical)

I suggest keeping [pharmaceutical](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pharmaceutical) for prescribed medications and keeping [recreational-drugs](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recreational-drugs) for illicit drugs.

Answer (score 1):

We have [money](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) and [currency](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currency) should they be merged?

Answer (score 0):

[congress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) synonym of [united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) or just remove [congress](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress)

Answer (score 0):

[fitness](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fitness) synonym of [exercise](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise)

Comment: Not sure about the side here

Answer (score 0):

I question the value of the following tags: [time](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), [causality](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality) (seems too much like a meta tag to me), [force](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force), [lifestyle](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle), [networks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networks)