# Should we stop adding [fluoride]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we get rid of one of [fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride) and [fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation), and if so, which one?

[fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation) has a tag wiki and has 20 questions, while [fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride) lacks a wiki, and has 6 questions. Of the six questions tagged [fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride), all of them are either tagged with [fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation), or have fluoridation in their title.

Logically speaking, all questions about fluoridation are about fluoride, but not all questions about fluoride are about fluoridation. Doing a [search](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=fluoride%20-%5Bfluoridation%5D%20-%5Bfluoride%5D%20is%3Aquestion) for questions with "fluoride" without either tag, I came across [Are cheap tea bags dangerous to your health due to high fluoride levels?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35494/are-cheap-tea-bags-dangerous-to-your-health-due-to-high-fluoride-levels) , which mentions fluoride but not fluoridation.

There are [two questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=fluorine%20-%5Bfluoridation%5D%20-%5Bfluoride%5D%20is%3Aquestion) mentioning fluorine (the name of the chemical element), but neither are primarily about the element.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a tag synonym.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tag synonym added. [fluoridation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoridation) -> [fluoride](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluoride)

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I would have preferred the other way ...

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305102/38765 it seems like more moderator works needs doing.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Ugh. Sorry. Will add to ToDo list.

Comment: @Oddthinking thank you.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Finally completed. Sorry for initial mistake, and delay in correction.